# Error while uploading Sitecore Package

Tags: packages, package-designer

Getting the following error while uploading (not installing), any Sitecore package:

```
9484 14:41:39 ERROR Could not resolve type name: **Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.CheckExtension, Sitecore.UploadFilter** (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
9484 14:41:39 ERROR Application error.

Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like configuration of your website includes reference to `Upload Filter tool`.

It is mentioned in `Secure the file upload functionality` Sitecore documentation:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/secure-the-file-upload-functionality.html

Now it looks like the dll is missing. You have 2 options:

- Copy right version of Upload Filter tool dll into `bin` folder
- Remove config that mentions `CheckExtension` class (most probably `App_Config\Include\UploadFilter.config`)

Answer (score 0):

As Marek mentioned, copy the `Sitecore.UploadFilter.dll` from Sitecore vanilla to the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<website>\bin` folder.